# Need to $post text, not value of a dropdown selected element

Tags: php, forms, post

```
<select name="months" id="months" >
        <option value="0" >Select Months *</option>
        <option value="3000" >6 Months</option>
        <option value="6000" >12 Months</option>
        <option value="9000" >18 Months</option>
</select>



$message .= "<br>Selected Months : " . $_POST['months'];
```

Need to $post text, not value of a dropdown selected element.

Comment: You create this HTML on the server side, hopefully dynamically, so you should already have an array that can be used to tell which text is connected to a certain value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

**array-config.php** - a config file with select box options that can be included as required.

```
<?php
$select_box = array(
  '0' => 'Select Months *',
  '3000' => '6 Months',
  '6000' => '12 Months',
  '9000' => '18 Months',
);
?>
```

**The HTML (PHP script)**

```
<?php
include_once('array-config.php');
echo '<select name="months" id="months">';
foreach($select_box as $key => $val) {
   echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $val . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

**Form post retrieval script**

```
<?php
include_once('array-config.php');
$message .= "<br>Selected Months : " . $select_box[$_POST['months']];
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

**You can not post the text. You can post the value only of any input type.**

To post the text change the select box:

```
<select name="months" id="months" >
        <option value="0" >Select Months *</option>
        <option value="6 Months" >6 Months</option>
        <option value="12 Months" >12 Months</option>
        <option value="18 Months" >18 Months</option>
</select>
```

OR

If you want to post text and value then use a hidden field to store the text of selected item before submit the form put the text in that hidden field by JS or jQuery. and you will get the text by that hidden field.

Comment: value is only being used for calculations ... i need text to be posted. Is there any solution ?

Comment: @SyedSaadImran I have write the advise in the answer use that. see the answer.

Comment: It is never needed or beneficial to repeat an option's text as its `value` attribute -- just omit the `value` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `value` then:

```
<select name="months" id="months" >
        <option value="0" >Select Months *</option>
        <option value="6 Months" >6 Months</option>
        <option value="12 Months" >12 Months</option>
        <option value="18 Months" >18 Months</option>
</select>
```

After all, it is the VALUE that is posted.

Comment: value is only being used for calculations ... i need text to be posted

Comment: @SyedSaadImran If you need the value there for calculations (in JS I assume?) then you might want to write a custom JS function to modify the `value` prior to sending the form. The `POST` will only EVER send the `value` no matter what you do.